# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar de control en C# al presionar la tecla Enter?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Estoy tratando de utilizar el mouse lo menos posible y para ello necesito saber si existe alguna forma de poder cambiar de control al presionar la tecla `Enter`.

La idea que tengo es que si estoy en un formulario con diversos controles, más que todo estoy utilizando controles de tipo `TextBox` pero podría tener `DateTimePickers` o `ComboBox`; que a la hora de presionar `Enter` salte al siguiente control, utilizando el orden que se le da a los mismos al crearlos en el formulario con la propiedad `TabIndex`.

```
private void txtOrdenServicio_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)13)
        {
            Cargar_OrdenesServicio();
            txtRazonTrabajo.Focus();
        }
    }
```

Con el código anterior lo he puesto en uno de los eventos `KeyPress` pero si tengo 10 `TextBox` tendría que colocar el control que sigue manualmente.
Estoy trabajando con Windows Form.

¿Existe alguna forma de poder lograr este salto?

Comment: De haberla, la hay, has intentado algo para lograr lo que quieres? De ser así, muestranos esa porción de tu código y conseguiras la ayuda de mas desarrolladores! Otra cosa, que tecnología utilizas, windows forms o wpf, etc..

Comment: He estado tratando de usar el KeyPress de los Textbox y preguntando si la tecla presionada ha sido el Enter para poder derivarlo al siguiente control pero es algo bastante tedioso hacerlo en cada caja de texto, no se si hay alguna forma de hacer una rutina que haga eso sin importar en el control donde este el Focus.
Estoy trabajando en Windows Forms.

Comment: Pues, para asignarle el foco al control que quieres desde cualquier control necesitas el evento `OnKeyDown` dentro de cada control para que envíe el foco a otro control, pero muestra esa parte que has intentado con `KeyPress` para ver como podemos ayudarte

Comment: Lo agrego aquí en el comentario? o lo pongo arriba en la pregunta?

Comment: Edita la pregunta, es mejor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para pasar al otro control solo necesitas manejar el evento `OnKeydown` del control con el que quieres trabajar.

Ejemplo:

```
private void TextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // Algúna regla para evitar que se salte al otro control?
    if (e.KeyCode.Equals(Keys.Enter))
        System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
}
```

O el ejemplo 2:

```
private void TextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // Algúna regla para evitar que se salte al otro control?
    if (e.KeyCode.Equals(Keys.Enter))
        otroControl.Focus();
}
```

Si tu metodo `Cargar_OrdenesServicio();` realiza algún tipo de acción sobre el control al cambiar su valor en el texto, te recomiendo poner dicha llamada dentro del evento `OnTextChanged`.

---

En VB.NET Lo que quieres sería un poco más facil de implementar, porque puedes manejar distintos eventos sin firma desde el mismo método, pero C# no admite implementar un evento a menos que este tenga su firma necesaria, para los eventos de tipo `Key`, la firma (signature) requerida lleva lo siguiente:

```
private void Nombre_Del_Control(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) { }
```

Dicho esto, puedes implementar el mismo metodo en todos los controles que sean compatibles con el evento `OnKeyDown` desde el explorador de eventos:

```
private void SaltarControl(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode.Equals(Keys.Enter)) SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
}
```

[Firmas y Sobrecargas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/aa691131(v=vs.71).aspx) si quieres entender un poco más de lo que te mencioné.

Espero te haya ayudado.

Comment: Por lo que me indicas tendría que utilizar el evento KeyDown y emular un TAB para que salte al siguiente control.
¿Qué es eso de la firma que mencionas?

Comment: Ya lo he editado.

Comment: @JuanManuelPalacios Por firma, lo más simple que puedo decir, es que no puedes llamar a un método con un parametro cuando este requiere 2.

Comment: Al colocar el SendKeys no lo está reconociendo, me dice lo siguiente:

SendKeys is a Type but is used like a Variable.

Me dice que debo crear una rutina con ese nombre.

Comment: [SendKeys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys(v=vs.110).aspx), es una clase que se encuentra dentro de `System.Windows.Forms` intenta agregando la directiva `using System.Windows.Forms` al archivo de código que estas editando.

Comment: Eso fue lo primero que verifiqué, esa directiva está en el Form desde que lo empecé a trabajar, de repente hay algo mas que agregar en algún otro lugar.

Comment: Ahhh ya, mi error, agrega `SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");`, Ya he editado al respuesta.

Answer (score 4):

La clave esta en usar el [GetNextControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.control.getnextcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx)() con este podras conocer cual es el proximo control que debe tomar el foco.

[Using Enter Key as a Tab](http://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/using-enter-key-as-a-tab/)

como veras el keypress lo defines a nivel del forma para hacerlo global

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    Control nextControl ;
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        nextControl = GetNextControl(ActiveControl, !e.Shift);
        if (nextControl == null)
            nextControl = GetNextControl(null, true);
        nextControl.Focus();
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
    }
}
```

tambien podrias evaluar usar el [Form.ProcessCmdKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.form.processcmdkey%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) para controlar aun mas general las taclas del form

Comment: hola @Leandro, gracias por tu respuesta, he probado el código que indicas pero al hacerle seguimiento me he dado cuenta que se detiene en todos los tipos de control, inclusive trata de darle el foco a los `labels`.
Está genial, pero tendría que validar el tipo de control siguiente antes de tratar de darle el foco.

Answer (score 0):

Para que funcione correctamente es importante que uses el evento **PreviewKeyDown**

'''

```
private void tbContra_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
{
      if (e.KeyCode.Equals(Keys.Enter))
          button1.Focus();
}
```

'''